How to make this MathML table take smaller space?
I have two MathML examples.
The first:
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="true" form="prefix">(</mo>
    <mtable columnalign="center center">
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mn>1</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mn>2</mn>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo fence="true" form="postfix">)</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>

It is rendered like this: 
And the second:
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="true" form="prefix">(</mo>
    <mtable columnalign="center center">
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mo fence="true" form="prefix">(</mo>
            <mn>1</mn>
            <mo fence="true" form="postfix">)</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mrow>
            <mo fence="true" form="prefix">(</mo>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mo fence="true" form="postfix">)</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo fence="true" form="postfix">)</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>

It is rendered like this: 
Which, in my opinion, doesn't look as great because it takes too much space. :(
Is it possible to make the second one take less space and maybe look almost like the first?
In LaTeX it looks more like I want:

LaTeX source, maybe that helps:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
\left(1\right) & \left(2\right)
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}

